# Can I make some fields on an Access form conditional?

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, conditional-statements

I am creating a database and I have a table where I am collecting if a patient has been or is currently on specific medications. 
I have a list of 17 medications that we care about and have a yes/no checkbox for each one. If a patient is or has ever been on one of these medications we want to collect 9 additional fields.

I want to create a form that lists only the medications and checkboxes. When the user checks a checkbox I then want the additional fields to appear for them to fill out.

Most patients will have only been on 2-5 of these medications, so I don’t want to clutter the form with unnecessary blank fields.

Is there a way to do this without VBA?  If no, will someone give me an example of what the VBA code should look like?

Thanks so much! We collect this data as part of an ongoing registry monitoring the long term safety of a specific research medication.  We usually collect this data differently when the patient is in clinic however, in lite of the pandemic we need to do this via telephone and this database will be crucial in ensuring the continued collection of this vital data!!

Thanks, 
Allen

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask], then improve question (edit)! E.g. show data model (tables structure/fields), sample data, actual output, expected output (all formatted as text/code)!

Answer (score -1):

What you can do is to rely on the fact that Yes/No fields are stored as 0 (False) and non-0 (True). You can then have a small piece of VBA code behind the form that adds all of the Yes/No fields to determine whether to display the additional text boxes or not:

```
Sub sCheckMedication()
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    If (Me!Medication1 + Me!Medication2 + Me!Medication3) <> 0 Then
        Me!txtMedicationNotes.Visible = True
    Else
        Me!txtMedicationNotes.Visible = False
    End If
sExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbclf & "sCheckMedication", vbOKOnly + vbCritical
    Resume sExit
End Sub
```

You would then call this procedure in the Form's Current event (to cover when the form is first loaded, and also when navigating between records), and also on the CheckBox's Click event:

```
Private Sub chkMedication1_Click()
    Call sCheckMedication
End Sub
```

Regards,